# Oracle sequence alternative

Tags: oracle, sequence

what is an alternative of sequence in Oracle, need to generate an ID for primary key column.

I have tried this one:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  game_id_seq START WITH 1000 INCREMENT BY 1;
game_id_seq.nextval
```

but it tells me:

> An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
>              For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
>              this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.

thanks

Comment: If it is a primary key, then there is no possibility of inserting a duplicate or forcing a duplicate through update until the key is valid. So you can still proceed with SEQUENCE.

Comment: Sequence wont work, if you use it in SQL Loader, DIRECT load option. But for it, Sequence is the best option.

Comment: Show your update or insert statement that uses the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a sequence that starts with the number 1000. If your table already contains data then make sure the sequence starts with a number larger than the largest number already in the table.

Comment: the max number is 250